# Visual Studio 2012 express for Web misses Command Prompt

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

i have Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web installed to do some ASP.NET programming but I am missing the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

I searched quite some time now, but it seems to be missing. Any idea where i could find it?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Comment: I don't know if the command line comes with the express edition, see what you have here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this directory contains only a single folder called "VDT" with some DLLs inside.

Comment: I searched around quite a bit tonight but haven't come up with it either sadly. Just curios, what do you need the command prompt for?

Comment: Hi @Andrew,
I think I need the Command Prompt in order to get some other color themes. I use this tutorial and am stuck on step 3: [Color Themes in VS2012 Express](http://alinconstantin.blogspot.de/2012/09/using-color-themes-with-visual-studio.html)
But perhaps the Command Prompt is not necessary - and "updateConfiguration" can be called somehow else?!? Any ideas?

Thanks Dominik

Comment: Did you make sure you're in the right directory before running “wdexpress.exe /updateconfiguration” ? Try to do "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE" first. The path might be different depending on where you installed visual studio

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew! The .exe is not called "wdexpress.exe" but "vwdexpress.exe" - but your post made me look a bit closer to the filenames. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://alinconstantin.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-color-themes-with-visual-studio.html For Web Express, deploy to "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpressExtensions" and force the configuration update with "VWDExpress.exe /updateconfiguration"

Answer (score 0):

you need to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress /updateconfiguration. what is missing in everyone's solution is "V" in WDExpress.exe when it comes to VS express edition