# Issues with Compiling C# Code from Command Prompt

Tags: c#, compilation, visual-studio-express

I am learning C#, and I want to learn how to compile code from the command prompt, in case I ever need to. The book I am using to learn has instructions that I tried to follow. I navigated to the directory with the file, named it with a .cs file extension, and tried **csc compiletest.cs** as I was told. (compiletest.cs is the name of the file) Whenever I try that, it tells me that "csc is not recognized as an internal or external command........." and so on. I tried adding the csc.exe file to the path as some forums told me, but with no luck. I have heard that I need to run the command through the Visual Studio customized command prompt, but I am unable to locate that. I am running Visual Studio Express 2012. If anyone knows how I can find the command prompt for that, I would much appreciate the help.

Comment: On the start menu, under your Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 folder, there should be another Visual Studio Tools folder, and under that are the available command prompt options. I'm not familiar with Express but there's a chance those tools aren't part of it. Seems [there's a way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14529981/74757) to force the command prompt shortcut installation for Express.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio. You can't run **any** application in Windows without providing a path, if that application's folder isn't on the PATH  variable. When you click on a shortcut, that contains the full path to the application to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .Net 4.0 or newer installed, you can find csc.exe under here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\

If you add this folder to your Windows %path%, you'll be able to compile code from anywhere.